# idat.exe -S -A close without error

Tags: ida, idapython, command-line

I have developed a idapython script and I run it using the following command:
`idat.exe -S"myscript.py" -L"logs.txt" -A .\mylib.so`

In `myscript.py` I appended the `exit(0)` in order to stop idat.exe, otherwise the command above never ends. But when I open the `logs.txt` file I find the following lines:

```
myscript.py: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\IDAPro\python\3\ida_idaapi.py", line 616, in IDAPython_ExecScript
    exec(code, g)
  File "myscript.py", line 49, in <module>
    exit(0)
  File "<frozen _sitebuiltins>", line 26, in __call__
SystemExit: 0
 -> OK
```

So, my question is, what is the correct way to stop the execution of `idat.exe` when I run a script with `-A`?

Comment: idaapi.qexit(0)

Answer (score 1):

For IDA 7.0+ you may better use `ida_pro.qexit(0)`.

> Stop execution of IDC program, close the database and exit to OS
> code: code to exit with

https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/197.shtml